# Javascript: Smoke-Logo effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I am trying to make a logo to have smoke all over it. I bummped into this jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/jonnyc/Ujz4P/5/ and now I am trying to change it so it goes over a logo
however it doesn't want to work.

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Smoke</title>
<style>
.container
{
  width: 360px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px solid black;
 }
 </style>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="smoke_effect.js"></script>
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div class="container">
   <img id="smoke-logo" src="images.jpg"/>
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

and all of the javascript on the left hand side in the jsfiddle I paste it in a docment called smoke_effect.js however I haven't change the code at all I just change the tag from "myCanvas" to "smoke-logo".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I made 2 big changes to your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ujz4P/1563/)

I changed the CSS to read:

```
#myCanvas{
    background:transparent;
}
```

and the draw function, instead of filling with semi-transparent black, just clears canvas.

```
// The function to draw the scene
function draw() {
    // Clear the drawing surface and fill it with a black background
    //context.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)";
    //context.fillRect(0, 0, 400, 400);
    context.clearRect(0,0,400,400);
    // Go through all of the particles and draw them.
    particles.forEach(function(particle) {
        particle.draw();
    });
}
```

This will allow you to put an image behind the smoke.

Comment: @Unsparing just change the css in Patrick's example to `background:transparent url([your image path]) top left no-repeat;` and it should work.